# MVC and jQuery data retrieval

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I am using mvc and jQuery and I am trying to display someone's profile with some additional institutions that the person belongs to.  I am new to this but I've done something like this in ProfileControler:

```
public ActionResult Institutions(int id)
    {
       var inst = fr.getInstitutions(id);
        return Json(inst);
    }
```

getInstitutions(id) returns Institution objects(with Name, City, Post Code etc.)
Then in a certain View I am trying to get the data with jQuery and display them as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.post("/Profile/Institutions", { id: <%= Model.Profile.userProfileID %> }, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function () {

                var new_div = $("<div>");

                var new_label = $("<label>");
                new_label.html(this.City);

                var new_input_b = $("<input>");
                new_input_b.attr("type", "button");

                new_div.append(new_label);
                new_div.append(new_input_b);

                $("#institutions").append(new_div);
            });
        });
    });
```

$("#institutions") is a div where i want to display all of the results. 
.post works correct for sure because certain institutions are retrieved from database, and passed to the view as Json result. But then I am affraid it wont itterate with .each.

Any help, coments or pointing in some direction would be much appriciated

Answer (score 1):

The above code will work if you [set the dataType to JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.post("/Profile/Institutions",
        { id: <%= Model.Profile.userProfileID %> }, 
        function (data) {
            $.each(data, function () {

                var new_div = $("<div>");

                var new_label = $("<label>");
                new_label.html(this.City);

                var new_input_b = $("<input>");
                new_input_b.attr("type", "button");

                new_div.append(new_label);
                new_div.append(new_input_b);

                $("#institutions").append(new_div);
            });
        },
        "json");
    });
```